# How to propagate an enum type in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, disassembly

I'd like to mark some data as being an enum, and have that automatically propagate to all uses of this piece of data. Both direct accesses to the data (e.g. `cmp data_with_enum_type, enum_value`), and future use by any register it is copied into (e.g. `mov al, data_with_enum_type | cmp al, enum_value`).

Is this possible in IDA, or something that could be straightforwardly scripted, or something an existing plugin may handle?